# Servlet Mapping Error appears when "@WebServlet" annotation is present

Tags: java, xml, servlets

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ajayramesh.jrecycled.servlets.Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I have a class called Login.java with an auto-generated annotation that says:

`@WebServlet("/login")`

right above my `HttpServlet` class extension declaration. When this annotation is present, I get the following error when I try to start my server:

```
The servlets named [LoginServlet] and [com.ajayramesh.jrecycled.servlets.Login] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/login] which is not permitted
```

I only have one definition in my `web.xml` and only a single `web.xml`. When I remove this annotation, the server works fine. To my understanding, annotations are not supposed to have an effect on the runtime of the program, and are only meant to optimize compilation? On a side note, what exactly does that annotation do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same mapping for both annotation and web.xml, you can use either one of it. App server treat it as duplicate url mapping.

Basically, declaring servlet and servlet-mapping elements in web.xml is equal to annotating a servlet class with @WebServlet.

Comment: Got it thanks. So did they both coexist in previous versions of Tomcat? I've seen example code with both of them.